# direct access to base class variables / objects c#

Tags: c#

```
public class myWorld
{
    public int data;
    public void ChangeData()
    {
        data = 10;
    }
}

public class myRobot : myWorld
{
    public void robotChangesData()
    {
        //how can i make the robot change the data in world?
    }
}
```

i understand (more or less) that this should not be done this way, and has been asked a thousand times, as every change should be through methods - but:

if we stay with the world and robot example, later on i want to have a method for the robot like: `robot.MoveBox(25)`
where the robot has to have access to the world, an object box, and make updates to the drawing objects (meshes, shapes etc.)
The only thing i can come up with now, is to pass for every method of the robot (like `movebox`, or `robotChangesData`) the whole world + box + drawing stuff as a 'ref' and he can change it then.. 
but the every method would look something like `robot.MoveBox(25, ref myworldObject, ref myworldBoxes,ref etc etc)`

Is this really the right way to go? or did i miss something important?

Comment: A `Robot` is not a `World`.  You're misusing inheritance.

Comment: You're misunderstanding `ref`.  http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe an example helps:

Your robot base class

```
public class RobotBase
{
    protected int data;

    // Reference to the world
    protected World _world;

    public RobotBase(World world)
    {
        _world = world;
    }

    public void ChangeData()
    {
        data = 10;
    }
}
```

Your robot class:

```
public class Robot : RobotBase
{
    public Robot(World world) : base(world)
    {}

    public void RobotChangesData()
    {
        //Change data in base
        data = 20;

        // Change data in world, the object is passed by reference, no need for further "ref" declarations
        _world.Terminate();
    }
}
```

Your world class:

```
public class World
{
    public void Terminate() 
    {
       // terminate world! noooess!
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, if there is nothing else for now, accept the answer so that others know that your problem is solved. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You don't to pass it as a ref.

Create a class/object representation for your model, and only pass that in as a paramter to your robot.

Exposed methods should correspond to varoables that can he changed.

Don't use refs and outs for each world/model state variable.